# Problema con PHPMAILER al enviar correos masivos

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Estoy creando una pantalla para enviar correos masivos a los usuarios que se han registrado. Todo funciona bien, pero cuando se envía el correo se pueden ver todos los destinatarios a los que he enviado el correoe electrónico y no quiero que se vea esto. Me gustaría que solo saliera el destinatario que resibió este correo, no todas las personas a las que le he enviado el correo.

Adjunto una imagen de como se ve al recibir el correo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que solo se vea "para mí" por ejemplo.

El código que he usado es:

```
$emailReceptor = $instancia -> query("SELECT * FROM USUARIO");
while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($emailReceptor)){
 $asunto = $_POST["txtAsunto"];
 $cuerpo = $_POST["txtCuerpo"];
 $correoCliente = $item['EMAIL'];
 $nombre = $item['NOMBRE'];
 $mail->addAddress($correoCliente, $nombre);    
                   
 $mail->isHTML(true);                                
 $mail->Subject = $asunto;
 $mail->Body    = $cuerpo;
       

 $mail->send();
}
```

La idea del while es recorrer la tabla usuario, creo que ese es el problema, pero no sé si hay otra opción que pueda usar.

Comment: En lugar de `addAddress()` prueba con `addBCC()`; no se verá sólo para tí, pero tampoco se verán el resto de los destinatarios.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario! Me ha servido correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Mientras se recorre la misma instancia de correo, al inicio de cada iteración se debe de declarar `$mail -> ClearAllRecipients()`, para indicar al gestor que se trata de otro email y así sucesivamente